# Commit changes and get rid of sqlite -journal file

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to familiarise my self with SQLite in order to use it alongside iOS apps in the future.

I was trying this `savepoint` method to backup my data until that point and I've noticed that an extra sqlite file has been created next to original sqlite file having *-journal* at the end.

My problem now is that I don't know how to commit changes that I made after *savepoint* to the actual sqlite file.

What I did:

```
sqlite> savepoint 230913;
sqlite>
```

Later I've tried

```
sqlite> release savepoint 230913;
Error: near "230913": syntax error
sqlite> release savepoint '230913';
Error: no such savepoint: 230913
sqlite>
```

Could anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use the `COMMIT` command to release all the savepoints. btw, have you tried naming your savepoint differently?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use plain numbers to name savepoints. (The latest SQLite rejects your first `savepoint` statement.)

You should use savepoint names that begin with a letter, but if you really want to use this particular name, you could quote it with double quotes:

```
SAVEPOINT "230913";
```

(Please note that you have to use the same name everywhere.)

Comment: There is any way to check the exact savepoint name through -journal file? Using Notepad++ or similar apps?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to clear my mind here. So, if does not allows numbers as name then .. how I succeed to have a -journal file?

Comment: A savepoint name is not a file name. Each journal file gets a more-or-less random file name.

Comment: OK. I've delete it and did it again using correct format this time. No serious lost as it was for testing purposes. Thank you.